# Whats the point of multiple zones on a dns server?

Tags: windows-10, dns

Update: Additionally, Why would you create a primary forward lookup zone, allow zone transfers and then create a secondary forward lookup zone on another server. If u only have 1 dns server for whatever reason then I guess it would make sense to forward information to other servers. I mean, I guess maybe it accelerates name resolution, but I mean is it really going to cut time down? Why not just add dns software to every server you have. Is it a security risk?
Thanks for info, Just trying to learn about dns.

PS, I asked this question in server fault but apparently this a a better forum for it so I am reposting. I think this question follows the guidelines but I am a relatively new poster so if it is not then please let me know!

Comment: [How DNS works](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/cc772774(v=ws.10).aspx)